# Plugin for intellisense on a textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, intellisense

Are there any jQuery plugins for doing intellisense in a textarea? (just javascript would work good as well)

Comment: Are you using VS2008? Can you be more specific on what you mean by "intellisense in a textarea" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [Autocomplete plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete) on textareas, specify your keywords inline in the code or pull them from a database, check this [demo page](http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/demo/).

Comment: another possible plugin : http://colinramsay.co.uk/intellisense/current/demo.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer; however the demo page is a 404 Not Found error now.